# Cannot initialize Object in onCreate() event Android

Tags: android

I usually initialize in `onCreate()` event when application start.
.
But when I put my code in `onCreate()` event:

```
preferenceManager = CallInfoPreferenceManager.getInstance();
recorder = new AudioRecorder(preferenceManager.getStartDate());
```

to initialize object but it return `preferenceManager = null`, `recorder = null`.

I think problem when I using parameter `Bunble savedInstanceState`.

Here my code like this:

```
private SharedPreferences sharedPref;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fileupload);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    // Initialize at here

    preferenceManager = CallInfoPreferenceManager.getInstance();
    recorder = new AudioRecorder(preferenceManager.getStartDate());
}
```

I don't know I must add more code to know more information?

UPDATED:

For more information:
This is UploadRecord class, I want initialize AudioRecord to use in this class.

```
public class UploadRecord extends AppCompatActivity {
    CallInfoPreferenceManager preferenceManager;

    AudioRecorder recorder;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPref;

    private final UploadServiceBroadcastReceiver uploadReceiver =
            new UploadServiceBroadcastReceiver() {

                @Override
                public void onProgress(String uploadId, int progress) {
                    //any code
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(String uploadId, Exception exception) {
                    //any code
                }

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(String uploadId, int serverResponseCode, byte[] serverResponseBody) {
                    //any code
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(String uploadId) {
                    //any code
                }
            };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fileupload);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        // Initialize at here

        preferenceManager = CallInfoPreferenceManager.getInstance();
        recorder = new AudioRecorder(preferenceManager.getStartDate());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        uploadReceiver.register(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uploadReceiver.unregister(this);
    }
}
```

My class `AudioRecorder` is:

```
public class AudioRecorder {

    static String fileName;

    MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
    private String a;
    ConfigPreferenceManager configPreferenceManager;

    public AudioRecorder(String startDate) {
        configPreferenceManager = ConfigPreferenceManager.getInstance();
        this.fileName = courseGet(startDate);
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    }

    public AudioRecorder() {
        configPreferenceManager = ConfigPreferenceManager.getInstance();
    }
}
```

In Log cat view show exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String kr.co.composer.callrecord.recorder.AudioRecorder.getFileName()' on a null object reference
System.err:     at kr.co.composer.callrecord.recorder.UploadRecord.MultipartUploadForRecordApp(UploadRecord.java:186)
```

In line 186 of file UploadRecord.java, I call class to initialize `AudioRecord()`.

And I debug it show values is `AudioRecord = null`.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: Yes, you must add more information for making your question understandable

Comment: @Joseph82 , Gennadii Saprykin: I updated my question. Can you see again and help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: Add log cat information or explain how you can tell it's "not working"  What do you expect to see?  What do you actually see?

Comment: Pretend like someone submitted a bug report to you and is expecting you to figure out what is wrong and fix it.   What would you do if one of your users said "It's not working" with no other information?

Comment: Please clearly explain your problem. What's not working or what's not initialized ?

Comment: @DaleWilson I updated my question. It working but it return values of Object is null.